# Will this RAM work with my Intel DX58SO motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm planning to add three DIMMS so I have 12 GB triple channel.

[Memory](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/?partid=kvr13n9s8/4) is:

- 4GB Module - DDR3 1333MHz
- Part Number: KVR13N9S8/4
- Specs: DDR3, 1333MHz, Non-ECC, CL9, 1.5V, Unbuffered, DIMM,

My motherboard is an [Intel DX58SO](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/000005844.html).

Will this RAM work with my motherboard?

Comment: Yes it will....but you are near the voltage limit so you won't be able to overclock the memory. But check the supported memory configurations all modules should be filled with the same size and frequency for best performance